# Merge h264 and h.264 tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Like the title says. Both tags exist, but we only need one. I'm partial to [h.264](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/h.264) over [h264](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/h264). It also has double the questions.

Comment: I'd agree with you - let's see what others think as well. If there is general agreement, it's an easy merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

h.264 is the proper name and has more questions and actually had 2 questions tagged with both h264 and h.264.  I have created a synonym and combined them.